# Who writes the Dragon Ball Heroes manga?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

So now aside the Dragon Ball Super manga aparently there is also a Dragon Ball Heroes manga. Who writes the Dragon Ball Heroes manga? Does Akira Toriyama has any involvement in it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toyotarō (とよたろう) is the author of the spin-off manga Dragon Ball Heroes: Victory Mission, which debuted in the November 2012 issue of V-Jump and the illustrator of the Dragon Ball Super manga version. He is Akira Toriyama's chosen successor.[1]
http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Toyotar%C5%8D

Comment: So the Dragon Ball Heroes manga has the same writer than the Dragon Ball Super manga and Toriyama made some of the character designs. I guess it isnt so "untrue" to Dragon Ball as people states it to be